# Android testing in Android Studio using Robolectric issue

Tags: gradle, robolectric, android-testing, supportmapfragment

First of all I would like to declare my frustration for the lack of proper testing infrastructure in Android... or maybe I am retarded, I don't know... 
I eventually managed to setup [android-test-plugin](https://github.com/square/gradle-android-test-plugin) and I wrote a couple of tests for an activity that includes in its layout a `CustomMapFragment` which is a class I wrote that extends `SupportMapFragment`.
 All my tests that try to get an instance of this activity using:

```
activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class).create().get();
```

fail with:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap$OnInfoWindowClickListener

at activity's `setContentView`.

The activity's xml is the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/customMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            class="com.myproject.CustomMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there a workaround/solution for this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I share your frustration. I have the same problem, but I'm unable to run any test because I get a NoClassDefFoundError on maps classes when Robolectric tries to load classes, so even a assertTrue(true) test fails. Here's my question with the error I get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434217/robolectric-fails-to-run-tests-with-google-play-services-maps

Comment: I think it is a generic issue, not directly connected to maps, because I was getting the same error with some classes that where using Google cloud messaging. It is nice to know that there are people that understand you :) in case somebody answers here I'll tell you.

Comment: How did you add the google play services dependency? Using the google repository or in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have temporary solution. The problem seems to be that the android-test-plugin in unable to read an aar file. My solution is to add a dependency to the jar file instead only to testCompile, like this

```
testCompile files('YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_FOLDER/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar')
```

Like this I'm able to run a simple test, for example creating a LatLng and checking if it's not null, without errors. Hope it helps.

**Edit**

A better solution thanks to SuperJugy on github is to apply the fix in this commit https://github.com/SuperJugy/gradle-android-test-plugin/commit/d5b7836cf7278dc9d0fe765b635de60c33911d72

Comment: As soon as I have some time to test this, I will accept your answer. Anyway though, thanks a lot @alex.

Comment: Ok I give up...I actually managed to overcome these "NoClassDefFoundErrors" but now I get "java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!" as if Robolectric is added in the classpath before android.jar. Anyway building the last version of android-test-plugin seems to have fixed the previous problem, thus I am going to accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Eh, I'm fighting one problem after another too, I actually gave up writing tests for now. I had to use a snapshot version of robolectric because of an issue with styles and this version doesn't find resource files...